# Geolocation: UTM to Geodetic translation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, coordinates, utm

Maybe there's a better place to ask this, but I figured maybe someone has come into this problem before and can give me a hand with it.

I have a bunch of locations (36k) and they are represented using SIRGAS2000 (UTM 21s) coordinates. I need some way of converting them to traditional LatLng (Geodetic) format so I can upload them to my database and use those coords with Google Maps API.

Has any of you ever bumped into something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I just found a JS library for this task. It will convert from and to various types of coordinates.

Here's a link to it in case anyone needs it ...

http://www.jstott.me.uk/jscoord/

Some examples in there too